# What does it exactly mean by Factory Data Reset?

Tags: android, memory-management, reset, android-memory

I have seen this a lot but always wanted to know how Factory Data reset works on an android device? What its the internal mechanism and what are the stuff that it clears ? Is there any specific partition that it clears ?
Any knowledge is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factory Data Reset removes user data, third party applications, and returns your phone to the condition it was when shipped from the factory.

> When performing a factory reset:
>
> - /system is untouched since it's normally read-only anyway
>     /data is formatted
> - /cache is formatted
> - /sdcard is not touched unless you specify. Note that apps on the sdcard will still be erased.
>
> So, to answer your question, the system is not reflash end, but instead the data and cache partitions are formatted.

[from here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51927/how-does-an-android-factory-reset-work)